# value is not getting when navigating from one window to another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, navigation

if am navigating to another window for updation it the selected row resetting to null..if updation is done in the same home page,am getting that value and can update..if i hav different viewmodel for each view ,then for displaying data in a new window that hav a different viewmodel,how can i do that one too..

This is my employee View model code

```
namespace EmployeeRegistration
{
    class EmployeeViewModel : WindowItem, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {

        #region Declarations
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
        SqlCommand insertCommand = null;
        SqlCommand selectCommand = null;
        SqlCommand updateCommand = null;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = null;
        DataTable employeeTable = null;
        DataSet sqlDataSet = null;
        EmployeeModel employee;
        private ICommand newEmployeeCommand;
        private ICommand searchEmployeeCommand;
        private ICommand saveEmployeeCommand;
        private ICommand getEmployeeCommand;
        public ICommand bindControlValueCommand;
        public ICommand selectEmployeeCommand;
        public ICommand updateDetailsCommand;
        private Window window;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public EmployeeViewModel()
        {
            employee = new EmployeeModel();
            SaveEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(saveEmployeeDetail));
            SearchEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(searchEmployee));
            GetEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(getEmployee));
            SelectEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(selectEmployeeDetails));
            NewEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(newEmployeeWindow));
            UpdateDetailsCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(updateEmployeeDetails));
            bindControlValueCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(bindControlValues));
            Id = WindowsId.MainWindow;
            Function = ProcessMessage;
            WindowsManager.Add(Id, Function);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        //public EmployeeModel _Employee;
        //public EmployeeModel Employee
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        return _Employee;
        //    }
        //    set
        //    {
        //        _Employee = value;
        //        OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
        //    }
        //}

        public DataRowView selectedEmployee;
        public DataRowView SelectedEmployee
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedEmployee;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedEmployee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
            }
        }
        private DataTable employeeDatatable;
        public DataTable EmployeeDatatable
        {
            get { return employeeDatatable; }
            set
            {
                employeeDatatable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeDatatable");

            }
        }
        public int Emp_ID
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Emp_ID;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Emp_ID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Emp_ID");
            }
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.FirstName;
            }
            set
           {
                employee.FirstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                //this.DetailView = new HomeViewModel(value);
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.LastName;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.LastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
        public DateTime Dob
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Dob;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Dob = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Dob");
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Age = DateTime.Today.Year - Dob.Year;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Age");
            }

        }
        public string Street1
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Street1;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Street1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Street1");
            }
        }
        public string Street2
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Street2;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Street2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Street2");
            }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.City;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.City = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.State;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.State = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
        public string ZipCode
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.ZipCode;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.ZipCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ZipCode");
            }
        }
        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.PhoneNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.PhoneNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
            }
        }
        public string MobileNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.MobileNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.MobileNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MobileNumber");
            }
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Email;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }
        public string Web
        {
            get
            {
                return employee.Web;
            }
            set
            {
                employee.Web = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Web");
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Commands
        public ICommand UpdateDetailsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return updateDetailsCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                updateDetailsCommand = value;
            }
        }
        public ICommand SelectEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return selectEmployeeCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                selectEmployeeCommand = value;
            }
        }
        public ICommand SaveEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return saveEmployeeCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                saveEmployeeCommand = value;
            }
        }
        public ICommand SearchEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return searchEmployeeCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                searchEmployeeCommand = value;
            }
        }

        public ICommand GetEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return getEmployeeCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                getEmployeeCommand = value;
            }
        }
        public ICommand NewEmployeeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return newEmployeeCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                newEmployeeCommand = value;
            }
        }
        public ICommand BindControlValueCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return bindControlValueCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                bindControlValueCommand = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region SubMethods
        public void newEmployeeWindow()
        {
            WindowsManager.SendMessage(WindowsId.MainWindow, null, ActionId.OpenWindow);
        }

        private bool ProcessMessage(object args, ActionId action)
        {
            if (action == ActionId.OpenWindow)
            {
                if (window == null)
                {
                    window = new UpdateEmployeeDetails();
                }
                window.Show();
                return true;
            }
            if (action == ActionId.CloseWindow)
            {
                if (window == null)
                    return false;
                window.Close();
                window = null;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void bindControlValues()
        {

            this.Emp_ID = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEmployee.Row.ItemArray[0]);
            try
            {
                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                selectCommand = new SqlCommand(AppConstants.StoredProcedures.GetDataProcedure, sqlConnection);
                selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Emp_ID, SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.Emp_ID; ;

                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
                sqlDataSet = new DataSet();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDataSet);
                this.FirstName = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                this.LastName = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                this.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());
                this.Age = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString());
                this.Street1 = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                this.Street2 = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                this.City = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                this.State = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                this.ZipCode = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].ToString();
                this.PhoneNumber = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
                this.MobileNumber = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][11].ToString();
                this.Email = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
                this.Web = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][13].ToString();
            }

        }

        private void selectEmployeeDetails()
        {

            WindowsManager.SendMessage(WindowsId.MainWindow, null, ActionId.OpenWindow);

        }

        public void updateEmployeeDetails()
        {
            this.Emp_ID = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEmployee.Row.ItemArray[0]);
            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
                sqlConnection.Open();

                updateCommand = new SqlCommand(AppConstants.StoredProcedures.UpdateProcedure, sqlConnection);
                updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Emp_ID, SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.Emp_ID;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.FirstName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.FirstName;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.LastName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.LastName;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Dob, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Dob);
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Age, SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.Age);
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Street1, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Street1;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Street2, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Street2;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.City, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.City;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.State, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.State;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.ZipCode, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.ZipCode);
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.PhoneNumber, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.PhoneNumber);
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.MobileNumber, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.MobileNumber);
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Email, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Email;
                updateCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Web, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Web;
                int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You Have Updated Successfully");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
                updateCommand.Dispose();
            }

        }

        public void saveEmployeeDetail()
        {
            int count1 = 0;
            try
            {
                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                insertCommand = new SqlCommand(AppConstants.StoredProcedures.InsertProcedure, sqlConnection);
                insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.FirstName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.FirstName;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.LastName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.LastName;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Dob, SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Dob);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Age, SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(this.Age);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Street1, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Street1;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Street2, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Street2;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.City, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.City;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.State, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.State;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.ZipCode, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.ZipCode);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.PhoneNumber, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.PhoneNumber);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.MobileNumber, SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt64(this.MobileNumber);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Email, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Email;
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Web, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.Web;
                count1 = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (count1 > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(AppConstants.Messages.SuccessMessages.InsertSuccess);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
                insertCommand.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void getEmployee()
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
                sqlConnection.Open();

                selectCommand = new SqlCommand(AppConstants.StoredProcedures.SelectProcedure, sqlConnection);
                selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
                employeeTable = new DataTable();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(employeeTable);
                EmployeeDatatable = null;
                EmployeeDatatable = employeeTable;
            }

        }

        public void searchEmployee()
        {
            //employee.Emp_ID = SelectedEmployee.Row["Emp_ID"].ToString();
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
            sqlConnection.Open();

            //Searching the Employee using Stored Procedure by passing the Firstname as parameter
            selectCommand = new SqlCommand(AppConstants.StoredProcedures.SearchProcedure, sqlConnection);
            selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.FirstName, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = employee.FirstName;
            selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
            employeeTable = new DataTable();
            sqlAdapter.Fill(employeeTable);
            EmployeeDatatable = null;
            EmployeeDatatable = employeeTable;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

this is my xaml for home

```
<Window x:Class="EmployeeRegistration.Home"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:EmployeeRegistration"
        Title="Home" Height="595" Width="1096">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <View:EmployeeViewModel></View:EmployeeViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetEmployeeCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="myErrorTemplate">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.75" Grid.Column="0">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyControl" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource myErrorTemplate}" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Height="984" Width="1089">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="35" />
            <RowDefinition Height="44"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
            <RowDefinition Height="49" />
            <RowDefinition Height="56" />
            <RowDefinition Height="43" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="37"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="39*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="42*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="453*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="538"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="121" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="149" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="182" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    </Grid> 

</Window>
```

this is my update window xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EmployeeRegistration.UpdateEmployeeDetails"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:View="clr-namespace:EmployeeRegistration"
        Title="UpdateEmployeeDetails" Height="575" Width="614">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <View:EmployeeViewModel></View:EmployeeViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding BindControlValueCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Please elaborate some more on your problem, it is not really clear what you are asking ...

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `DataContext` in your ProcessMessage-Command to the new window:

```
    private bool ProcessMessage(object args, ActionId action)
    {
        if (action == ActionId.OpenWindow)
        {
            if (window == null)
            {
                window = new UpdateEmployeeDetails();
                window.DataContext = this;
            }
            window.Show();
            return true;
        }
        if (action == ActionId.CloseWindow)
        {
            if (window == null)
                return false;
            window.Close();
            window = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```